# Data manipulation with pandas: averaging first and last, second and second last and so on

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

hello I have cleaned some data so it looks like this

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 6 | 7 |
| 7 | 8 |
| 8 | 9 |
| 9 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 12 | 9 |
| 11 | 8 |
| 10 | 7 |
| 9 | 6 |
| 8 | 5 |
| 7 | 4 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 0 | 7 |

I want to have a new 2 columns with column A having average of first and last, second first and one before last and so on. and the same thing for column B with corresponding average of first and last, second and one before last etc.

Is this possible ?

expected result
[image]

Comment: Could you share expected results?

Comment: @Elkhan I have added the expected result to the question. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

if your data is in df_temp then the following code should work

```
col_list=["A","B"]

for col in col_list:
       temp_list=df_temp[col].to_list()
       temp_list.reverse()
       df_temp[col+"_reversed"]=temp_list
       df_temp[col+"'(Average)"]=(df_temp[col]+ df_temp[col+"_reversed"])/2

length=df.shape[0]
if (length % 2) == 0:
    df_result=df_temp.loc[0:(length/2),[x+"'(Average)" for x in col_list]]
else:
    df_result=df_temp.loc[0:(length/2)+1,[x+"'(Average)" for x in col_list]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have even number of rows in the dataframe, here is one approach

```
i = np.arange(len(df) // 2)
partitions = [*i, *i[::-1]] # partitioned indices

df.groupby(partitions).mean()
```

Alternative approach

```
n, v = len(df) // 2, df.values
pd.DataFrame((v[:n] + v[n:][::-1]) / 2, columns=df.columns)
```

Result

```
       A    B
0    0.0  4.0
1    1.0  3.5
2    2.0  3.0
3    3.0  2.5
4    4.0  3.0
5    5.0  4.0
6    6.0  5.0
7    7.0  6.0
8    8.0  7.0
9    9.0  3.0
10   5.5  3.5
11  11.5  8.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full exact code that you need:
Assuming an even number of rows:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4,5, 6, 7, 8, 9,1, 12, 11, 10, 9,8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
                 'B': [1, 2, 3, 4,5, 6, 7, 8, 9,0,0,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,1,3,5,7]})


df['A (Average)'] = ''
df['B (Average)'] = ''

len_of_Df=len(df)

    
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if (len_of_Df)/2 ==i:
        break
    else:
        df.at[i,'A (Average)'] = (df.at[i,'A'] + df.at[len_of_Df-i-1,'A'])/2
        df.at[i,'B (Average)'] = (df.at[i,'B'] + df.at[len_of_Df-i-1,'B'])/2
```

Output Dataframe:

| A | B | A (Average) | B (Average) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0.0 | 4.0 |
| 1 | 2 | 1.0 | 3.5 |
| 2 | 3 | 2.0 | 3.0 |
| 3 | 4 | 3.0 | 2.5 |
| 4 | 5 | 4.0 | 3.0 |
| 5 | 6 | 5.0 | 4.0 |
| 6 | 7 | 6.0 | 5.0 |
| 7 | 8 | 7.0 | 6.0 |
| 8 | 9 | 8.0 | 7.0 |
| 9 | 0 | 9.0 | 3.0 |
| 1 | 0 | 5.5 | 3.5 |
| 12 | 9 | 11.5 | 8.5 |
| 11 | 8 |  |  |
| 10 | 7 |  |  |
| 9 | 6 |  |  |
| 8 | 5 |  |  |
| 7 | 4 |  |  |
| 6 | 3 |  |  |
| 5 | 2 |  |  |
| 4 | 1 |  |  |
| 3 | 1 |  |  |
| 2 | 3 |  |  |
| 1 | 5 |  |  |
| 0 | 7 |  |  |